# Is aegir a good choice for me?

Tags: 7, aegir, subsites

I want to use aegir for a website that users can create their own sub-sites.

From aegir installation guide:

> when a new site is installed, the web server will be automatically configured (vhost) and restarted

Does this mean that every time a new subsite will be created, server restarts and will be out of access for a few seconds?

Comment: What you mean by sub-sites? subdomains or sites with their own url but the same code-base or folder base sub-sites?

Answer (score 2):

Aegir is a powerful tool to manage hosting environments, deploy new versions of your site, clone a live site to a testing environment... Stuff like that. I don't know which kind of users you're talking about, but I would only give access to experienced Drupal developers. If you want 'normal' end users of a site to be able to setup their own subsite, maybe http://drupal.org/project/subdomain is right for you.

Answer (score 2):

The whole server doesn't restart when a site is added, only Apache, and it's just a graceful restart, so no real downtime..

Also, if what you mean by 'subsite' is http://example.com/subsite1, /subsite2, /subsite3, Aegir doesn't support that at this stage. Subdomains will work fine, but not 'subfolder' sites. See http://community.aegirproject.org/faq#Can_I_use_the_subdirectory_multisite_feature_of_Drupal_in_Aegir